# To the nearest degree, the solution of the equation $3\space\sin^2(x ) - 2\sin(x) = 1$ in the interval $[270^\circ, \space 360^\circ]$ is $x = ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This is the problem I have in my trigonometry packet. Can anyone give it a try?

I factored by doing:

$$\sin x(3\sin x - 2) = 1$$

Then divided $\sin x$:

$$ 3\sin x - 2 = \frac{1}{\sin x}$$

But then I got stuck.

Comment: I'll post the edit showing what I've tried. :)

Comment: The edit is up!

Comment: Once again: $360^\circ$ looks different from $360^o$ and the first is the standard notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rewrite the equation as
$$3(\sin x)^2-2\sin x-1=0.$$
Temporarily, let $w=\sin x$. So our equation can be rewritten as 
$$3w^2-2w-1=0.$$
This is a quadratic equation, so the solutions can be found by using the Quadratic Formula.  But it so happens that our polynomial factors nicely:
$$3w^2-2w-1=(3w+1)(w-1).$$
So the roots of the polynomial are given by $w=-1/3$ and $w=1$.

We want to find all angles between $270$ degrees and $360$ degrees whose sine is either $-1/3$ or $1$. There is no angle in the fourth quadrant whose sine is $1$. But there is one whose sine is $-1/3$.

The first quadrant angle whose sine is $1/3$ is (calculator) about $19.47$ degrees. So the fourth quadrant angle whose sine is $-1/3$ is about $360-19.47$ degrees.

**Remark:** If you enter the number $-1/3$ in the calculator, and press the "$\sin^{-1}$" button, then, if your calculator is in degree mode, you will get something like $-19.471221$.  The negative sign means that we are travelling *clockwise* from the positive $x$-axis. To get the answer in the more conventional style, between $270$ and $360$, *add* $360$ to the calculator's (negative) answer.

The type of factoring that you did is in general not a useful way of solving quadratic equations. In the notation I used above, we have $w(3w-2)=1$. Transforming to the standard shape quadratic equation $3w^-2w-1=0$ works nicely. The strategies you were trying unfortunately complicate the problem instead of simplifying it. It is important for future problems to be able to recognize "disguised" quadratics.

Comment: Thanks. We were doing problems (non-quadratic ones) where we needed to factor and so I used it on this one, not knowing it was a quadratic equation "in disguise". :)

Comment: @David: Mostly when you need to factor, it is useful to have all the terms together. There are some exceptions, like $x^2(x-3)=2(x-3)$, where it may be useful to note that $x$ can be $3$, but if it isn't we can cancel and get $x^2=2$. But even here, bringing stuff together works nicely and is not much more work, for $x^2(x-3)-2(x-3)=(x-3)(x^2-2)$ and you conclude that $x=3$ or $x=\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Is there any way I can direct message you? I have some other problems I think you can help me with. :]

Comment: @David: I think it is best to ask questions on this site. As you can see, answers ordinarily come very quickly. Often, there will be a variety of approaches.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** let $A = \sin (x)$ and solve the resulting polynomial.

One of the solutions will be $90$ degrees (or $\pi /2$ radians), which is not in the interval under consideration.

---

Edit - to comment on your recent edit.

The most common reason to factor something (at this level) is to use the "zero product property" (Integral Domain) when *one side of the equation is ZERO!*

So to start factoring before putting the equation in standard form is usually going to result in a dead end. Hopefully you can see the reasoning for a simpler example like $$x^2 - x = 6$$

Answer (score 1):

$$3\sin^2(x)-2\sin(x)-1=(3\sin(x)+1)(\sin(x)-1)$$

Thus

$$\sin(x)=1 \,  {\rm or} \sin(x)=-\frac{1}{3} \,.$$

$\sin(x)=1$ has no root in that interval, while $\sin(x)=-\frac{1}{3}$ can be found with a calculator...